# how does one determine the behaviour of post increment values when passed to macros

Tags: c, macros, post-increment, pre-increment

```
#define man(x,y)((x)>(y))?(x):(y);

int main()
{
    int i=10,j,k;
    j=5;
    k=0;

    k=man(++i,j++);
    printf("%d %d %d",i,j,k);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
12 5 12
```

Can anyone make it clear as to how the value of i,k is 12 and not 11.

Comment: expand the macro by hand and see how it looks.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but why are you writing the initialization so weirdly? Why not simply `int i = 10, j = 10; int k = man(++i, j++);`? That way it's readable and economical.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

The macro `MAN(x, y) ((x)>(y)) ? (x):(y);` returns the biggest number of given two numbers.

**Step 1:** `int i=10, j=5, k=0;` The variable `i`, `j`, `k` are declared as an integer type and initialized to value `10`, `5`, `0` respectively.

**Step 2:** `k = MAN(++i, j++);` becomes,

=> k = ((++i)>(j++)) ? (++i):(j++);

=> k = ((11)>(5)) ? (12):(6);

=> k = 12

**Step 3:** `printf("%d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k);` It prints the variable `i, j, k`.

In the above macro `step 2` the variable `i` value is incremented by `2` and variable `j` value is incremented by `1`.

**Hence the output of the program is 12, 6, 12**